# How can I elegantly write a function to get the unique property from an IEnumerable, if that exists?

Tags: c#

I want to write a function that goes through an IEnumerable.  For each item in the IEnumerable it gets an enum property.  If everything in the IEnumerable has the same value for that property, then that value is returned.  Otherwise, it returns null.  I can do this, but not elegantly.  Is there a Linq expression I can use?  See the UniqueOption function below.

```
namespace Play
{
public enum Option
{
    Tom,
    Dick,
    Harry
}

public class OptionHolder
{
    public Option Option { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return Option.ToString();
    }
}

public class Program
{
    /// <summary>
    /// The main entry point for the application.
    /// </summary>
    [STAThread]
    private static void Main()
    {
        Program p1 = new Program(Option.Tom, Option.Dick, Option.Harry);
        Console.WriteLine("1: "+p1.UniqueOption());     //should be null
        Program p2 = new Program(Option.Dick, Option.Dick, Option.Dick);
        Console.WriteLine("2: " + p2.UniqueOption());   //should be Dick
        Program p3 = new Program(Option.Harry);         
        Console.WriteLine("3: " + p3.UniqueOption());   //should be Harry
    }

    public Program(params Option[] options)
    {
        optionList = new List<OptionHolder>();
        foreach (Option option in options)
        {
            OptionHolder holder = new OptionHolder();
            holder.Option = option;
            optionList.Add(holder);
        }
    }

    /**
     * If all the OptionHolders in the Holders property have the same Option, return this.
     * Otherwise (there are no OptionHolders, or there is more than one but they hold different Options), return null.
     */
    public Option? UniqueOption()
    {
        Option? option = null;

        foreach(OptionHolder holder in optionList) {
            Option o = holder.Option;
            if (option == null)
            {
                option = o;
            }
            else if (option != o)
            {
                return null;
            }
        }
        return option;
    }

    private List<OptionHolder> optionList;

    public IEnumerable<OptionHolder> Holders
    {
        get { return optionList; }
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return String.Join(",", optionList);
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Distinct()` with `Take(2)` to stop enumerating the list as soon as two different options are found, then check whether exactly one distinct option was found (as opposed to zero or two):

```
public Option? UniqueOption()
{
    Option[] options = optionList.Select(holder => holder.Option).Distinct().Take(2).ToArray();
    return options.Length == 1 ? options[0] : (Option?)null;
}
```

**UPDATE:** To check how many values are actually enumerated, you can use the following helper method:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> Trace<T>(IEnumerable<T> values)
{
    foreach (T value in values)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Yielding {0}...", value);
        yield return value;
    }
}
```

Call it like this:

```
Option[] options = Trace(optionList).Select(holder => holder.Option).Distinct().Take(2).ToArray();
```

This shows that `p1` enumerates only `Tom` and `Dick`, not `Harry`.

Comment: This looks good Michael.  Are you sure it only enumerates enough values to get two distinct ones?  I might test this out to see.

Comment: Thanks Michael, you are right - that is an elegant and efficient solution.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand correctly then you can use Linq's `Distinct` method.

```
public Option? UniqueOption()
{
    var distinct = optionList.Select(x=> x.Option).Distinct();
    if(distinct.Count() == 1)
    {
        return distinct.First();
    }
    return null;
}

public Option? UniqueOptionOptimized()
{
    HashSet<Option> set = new HashSet<Option>();
    foreach (var item in optionList)
    {
        if (set.Add(item.Option) && set.Count > 1)
        {
            return null;
        }
    }

    if (set.Count == 1)
        return set.First();
    else
        return null;
}

public Option? UniqueOptionOptimized2()
{
    using(var distinctEnumerator = optionList.Select(x => x.Option).Distinct().GetEnumerator())
    {
        if(distinctEnumerator.MoveNext())
        {
            var firstOption = distinctEnumerator.Current;
            if(!distinctEnumerator.MoveNext())
                return firstOption;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: This solution would work but its inefficient.  If there are 1000 elements and the first two have different values for the property, there is no need to do anything with the other 998 elements.

Comment: @PaulRichards: I believe you want the whiskey in the barrel and the wife drunk at same time. Linq is everything but efficient! Either you want a Linq-way for elegance and versatility, or you choose an optimized but hard-way. My solution as well as the first of Sriram *ARE* Linq, other are not.

Comment: I realise that Linq isn't known for its efficiency @Mario Vernari.  However, the Any method doesn't necessarily iterate through every item. I already have my solutions, but I am going to have a think about this some more.

Comment: @SriramSakthivel: `Distinct(x => x.Option)` doesn't compile because `Distinct` takes an optional `IEqualityComparer`, not a selector. You should use `Select(x => x.Option).Distinct()` instead.

Comment: @MichaelLiu Good catch, Updated :)

Comment: @MichaelLiu You're talking about version3? Or... No riddles.. point it out or take advantage to edit it.

Comment: @MarioVernari LINQ isn't particularly inefficent in general; in fact most people tend to *think* that it's much less efficient than it is.  Of course, if its not used properly (for example, by using methods that iterate entire sequences when they could short circuit) it can result in poor performance.

Comment: @Servy: that's fine. However, the initial question was on writing the function in a Linq-fashion ("elegantly" he used). He did not asked for a performing way to achieve the same result. If you take a look, the winner answer is basically the same as mine, so no performance improvements.

Comment: @MarioVernari The accepted answer is the one that short circuits, which is the specific optimization that you are arguing isn't worth applying, and that you didn't apply.

Comment: @Servy: you are right! Now understand where is the trick: very nice.

Answer (score 0):

The below function should fit your needing. However, I tried it with a simpler app, but you should be able to arrange as you wish.

```
    public Option? UniqueOption(params Option[] args)
    {
        if (args == null)
            return null;  //or maybe throws?

        var d = args.Distinct().ToArray();
        return d.Length != 1
            ? d[0]
            : new Nullable<Option>();
    }
```

Comment: if  `d.Length == 0` then `d[0]` raise exception

Comment: This has the same performance issue as Sriram Sakthivel's solution.

Answer (score 0):

```
[STAThread]
private static void Main()
{

    Option tested = Option.Paul;
    Program p4 = new Program(Option.Paul, Option.Paul, Option.Paul);
    Console.WriteLine("4: " + p4.UniqueOption(tested));

}
public Option? UniqueOption(Option tested)
{
    if (optionList.All(o => o.Option == tested))
        return tested;

    return null;
}
```

Comment: My UniqueOption function has no parameter.  Your solution does not meet my requirements because we don't know what the value of the unique option is.

Answer (score 0):

Yet another variant:

```
public Option? UniqueOption()
{
    if(!optionList.Any()) return null;
    var first = optionList.First();
    return optionList.All(a => first.Option == a.Option) ? (Option?)first.Option : null;
}
```

Comment: This is a straightforward solution. However, if `optionList` were a deferred query instead of a `List<OptionHolder>`, the query would be evaluated multiple times.

Comment: @MichaelLiu yep, but in sample its list :-)

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using something that wasn't too different from my original solution. I'm going to take another look at this though, when I get some more time.

```
public Option? UniqueOption()
{            
        IEnumerator<OptionHolder> enumerator = Holders.GetEnumerator();
        bool hasMoreElements;
        Option? result=null;
        do
        {
           hasMoreElements = enumerator.MoveNext();
           if (hasMoreElements)
           {
              Option? option = enumerator.Current.Option;
              result = (result != null && result != option) ? null : option; 
           }
        } 
        while (hasMoreElements && result != null);
        return result; 
}
```